# Is it possible to restore SQL Server DB from transaction log (no MDF)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, restore, transaction-log, recovery

We had a SQL Server 2005 server that housed roughly 200 low/no traffic archive databases, and that server was not backed up to any other device.  The database files (MDF and LDF) were stored on a RAID array, and when the RAID controller failed we were concerned we were going to lose our data.  We sent the RAID controller and array to a data recovery company, and they were able to recover most of the files, but in some cases we have the transaction log but are missing the main data files.

Is it possible to restore the database to the last transaction (which should be just after the database was created) using just the transaction log, or is this something that can't be done?

Comment: Wow no backup plan?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I inherited a system with no backup plan.  Fortunately, nearly all the important functionality had been migrated off to another server literally minutes before it failed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to restore the database to the last transaction (which should be just after the database was created) using just the transaction log, or is this something that can't be done?

No, restoring a transaction log is sequential. Transaction log relies on [LSN (Log Sequence Number)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190411.aspx)

Also, you cannot restore your database with just transaction log. It requires the main database file (MDF) and NDF (secondary datafiles if there are any).

Comment: awesome answer. it must be +1

Comment: If the data is really important and there are no backups you can rely on, first fix the backup/restore story so you won't be in this situation again in the future. There is no "if", hardware and systems will fail so protect yourself. Then look at some of the .ldf reader tools out there from Apex, Toad, etc... It'll be a tedious manual effort but if you have the files, you'll get at least some of the data back.